# Why is LaTeX not using my font?

Tags: fonts

After reading a bit about fonts I decided that I want to use the schola font in my document, but for some reason LaTeX (I am using TeXstudio if this is relevant) does not use this font, despite me using the commands

> \fontfamily{qcs}
> \selectfont

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Could you please help me? Below you can see the preamble of my document with a sample text that replicates the problem on my PC.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\fontfamily{qcs}
\selectfont


\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}




\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{clrscode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage[babel,german=guillements]{csquotes}
%\addbibresource{library.bib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliography{library.bib}    


\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries \centering}{\huge \Roman{chapter}.}{10pt}{\huge}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=5cm, text width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}



\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\definecolor{darkspringgreen}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\definecolor{egyptianblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.2, 0.65}
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.49, 0.0}
\definecolor{byzantine}{rgb}{0.74, 0.2, 0.64}
\definecolor{royalazure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.22, 0.66}
\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{rgb}{0.01, 0.75, 0.24}
\definecolor{ashgrey}{rgb}{0.7, 0.75, 0.71}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definition}{Definition}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}  

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{lemma}{Lemma}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}  

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{corollary}{Corollary}
{colback=blue!25,colframe=blue!25!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}



\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem*{example*}{Example}
\newtheorem{reminder}{Reminder}


\newcommand{\jacobi}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\JNM}{\mathcal{J}_n^{-1}}
\newcommand{\JNP}{\mathcal{J}_n^{+1}}
\newcommand{\legendre}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\| {#1} \|}
\newcommand{\QR}[1][n]{\mathcal{QR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\QNR}[1][n]{\mathcal{QNR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\PSQR}[1][n]{\mathcal{PSQR}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\SQRT}[2]{\mathcal{SQRT}_{#2} {(#1)}}
\newcommand{\ZNZ}[1][n]{\mathbb{Z}/{#1}\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\ZNZX}[1][n]{(\mathbb{Z}/{#1}\mathbb{Z})^\times}


\begin{document}
    
This document is a sample document to 
test font families and font typefaces.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are selecting a font but not changing the document defaults and the default font is selected at `\begin{document}`

Comment: That's not the right way to set the main document font. You might use `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{qcs}`, but you'll get a not matching math font.

Comment: Please reduce your MWE, looks like there are (for the test case) a lot of useless statements and packages loaded that are not used. In this way it might be that you already see what package provokes the wrong font.

Comment: I'd rather suggest `\usepackage{fouriernc}\usepackage{tgschola}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers, I could solve my problem thanks to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to set the default font family, it's not sufficient to say

```
\fontfamily{<family>}\selectfont
```

in any place of the document. You have it in the preamble, but LaTeX always executes `\normalfont` at the beginning of the `document` environment.

The “correct” declaration is `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{<family>}`, but in general it's better to use font packages.

In your case, you can combine `tgschola` for text and `fouriernc` for math; the latter provides math letters compatible with New Century Schoolbook, which TeX Gyre Schola is a clone of.

The order of declarations should be

```
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tgschola}
```

because `fouriernc` chooses its own clone of New Century Schoolbook.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simpler than the other answers suggest.  You select

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

after you change `\fontfamily`.  This overwrites your font selection with Latin Modern.  Change this to:

```
\usepackage{tgschola}
```

as egreg recommends.  Or load `fouriernc` and `tgschola` after it if you still want Latin Modern Sans and Latin Modern Mono.  If you started by copying the package list from a document template, it’s a good idea to try commenting out each package you’re not sure you need, and see if you actually do.

In the modern toolchain, you could replace most of your preamble with

```
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm} % The order in which you load these matters.
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% Other packages you need, such as graphicx and xcolor.
% You can drop most of the packages, including latexsym,
% amssymb, fontenc, inputenc, amsfonts and lmodern.

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
```

This will use the modern OpenType versions of the fonts.

Comment: I notice I got a downvote. I’d appreciate hearing how my answer could be improved.